# How to stop a Vimeo video with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

When I hide a YouTube video, it stops playing. However, this is not the case for Vimeo videos. Is there another way to stop a Vimeo video?

Comment: Are you using the Universal embed code or the Flash embed code?

Comment: It's with the iframe tag

Answer (score 62):

First, add an ID to your iFrame. Then add this to your javascript close window click function:

```
var $frame = $('iframe#yourIframeId');

// saves the current iframe source
var vidsrc = $frame.attr('src');

// sets the source to nothing, stopping the video
$frame.attr('src',''); 

// sets it back to the correct link so that it reloads immediately on the next window open
$frame.attr('src', vidsrc);
```

Comment: Actually this one works all browsers even ie7, closing videos smooth!

Comment: When the src attribute is added it makes the animation jump.

Answer (score 18):

I recently needed to pause a Vimeo video that was inside a Bootstrap modal when the modal was closed.

The Vimeo video was embedded in an iframe.

This is what worked for me:

```
$("#my-bootstrap-modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var div = document.getElementById("my-bootstrap-modal");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    iframe.postMessage('{"method":"pause"}', '*');
});
```

Comment: @johna: Do you have a reference to the api docs for the vimeo methods that are available to use when using postMessage in an iframe embedded vimeo video?

Comment: @j4v1, I couldn't find anything specific to postMessage and I never needed to do anything other than pause, but I presume the player reference would apply (but need to change to use postMessage): https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference

Comment: Modal? Modal dialog?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, what is your question? Something to do with Bootstrap modals (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/)?

Answer (score 12):

Vimeo has [a JavaScript API](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) that allows you to access and invoke many properties and methods on the video player (including pausing the video and also unloading it completely). They also have an [API Playground](http://player.vimeo.com/playground) and some [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript).

[Edit]

Since you mention that you use the Universal Embed Code, here are some caveats from the web site:

> With the Universal Embed Code, the only way to interact with the player is by using [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage). postMessage is a relatively new development, so it's oly available in the following browsers: Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3+, Safari 4+, Chrome, and Opera 9+.
>
> Because of the complexities involved with postMessage, we've written a JS mini-library that does all the hard work for you! You can find it on the [downloads page](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/downloads) or you can see some examples [below](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js#examples).

Comment: Github uri is an older one, better point to https://github.com/vimeo/player.js

Answer (score 6):

To restore the SRC attribute, use the following before clearing:

```
var source = $('iframe#yourVideoId').attr('src');
```

Next, SRC attribute clear:

```
$('iframe#yourVideoId').attr('src', '');
```

Callback previous SRC attribute:

```
$('iframe#yourVideoId').attr('src', source);
```

Comment: $('iframe#yourVideoId').attr('src','about:blank'); is more accurate.

Answer (score 4):

```
    var vidUrl = $("iframe#video-frame").attr('src');


    //Basically stops and starts the video on modal open/close
    $('#video').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("iframe#video-frame").attr('src','');
    });

    $('#video').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("iframe#video-frame").attr('src', vidUrl);
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Another answer along the lines of David's...you can use jQuery to clear the SRC attribute of the iFrame.

```
$('iframe#targetID').attr('src','');
```

I'm using this with a Vimeo video and a lightbox effect. When the lightbox is triggered again, I add the video URL back to the iFrame SRC before showing it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Vimeo JavaScript API, it can be done with:

```
player.unload()
```

https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#unload-promisevoid-error

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove and put the src back on.

```
    $('#helpVideo').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        video_src = $('iframe').attr('src')
        $('iframe').attr('src',video_src)
    })
```