# Pause HTML5 video in Owl Carousel on slide

Tags: jquery, html, owl-carousel

Im using Owl Carousel 2.0.0-beta.2.4 and in one slide I have a HTML5 video. What I want to do is when I change slide I want the video to be paused or stopped if pause is not possible. The slide can be changed by drag, touch, next and prev buttons and by keyboard arrows.

My script looks like this right now:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    URLhashListener: true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash',
    nav: true,
    autoHeight : true,
    video:true,
});

var owl = $('.owl-carousel').data('owlCarousel');

$(document.documentElement).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        owl.prev();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        owl.next();
    }
});
```

I have heard about onMove or callback functions but I don't quite understand them.

Comment: What does your current code not do/do wrong that you want to fix?

Comment: @dg99, like I have written in my text I want to pause my video (if it's played) when I change slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
        onTranslate: function() {
        $('.owl-item').find('video').each(function() {
            this.pause();
        });
    }
```

So final code for my owl-carousel is:

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    URLhashListener: true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash',
    nav: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    video: true,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 100,
    onTranslate: function() {
        $('.owl-item').find('video').each(function() {
            this.pause();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the latest Owl Carousel 2 :/ I think because they changed how they handle video

Comment: I went for the brutal approach, which is to kill the iframe `$('SELECTOR iframe').prop('src','')` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145990/how-to-stop-a-vimeo-video-with-jquery))

Answer (score 0):

Check out the doc: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html

```
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $(".owl-carousel video").get(0).pause();
})
```

Comment: I have tried that. That does not make it work. What I want is to pause my HTML5 video when I change slide by keyboard, dragg, touch or select next or prev slide by navigation.

Comment: You'll need to listen to the proper events, and to find out you will need to read the doc.